# Related accounts badges not rendering with avatars

Tags: bug, status-norepro, related-accounts

#### Issue Description

Some of the badges on the related accounts page are not rendering with an avatar, even though the profile on the site they represent has an avatar.

[image: Shaun's related accounts badges]

#### Reproduction Links

- Badge Image Links

  - [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/flair/8033.png)
  - [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/flair/456.png)
- Affected Sites (avatars are present)

  - [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/8033/shaun)
  - [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/456/shaun)
- Related Accounts Pages (to reproduce as seen in the screenshot)

  - [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333652/shaun?tab=accounts)
  - [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3107/shaun?tab=accounts)

Comment: strange!, the whole account boxes are single images actually, how could that be missing in image? may be during image creation? but couldn't repro on my machine.

Comment: I'm betting on a connection issue - they all are different images URL-wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce this, they look fine on your account

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151410/shaun?tab=accounts

Comment: Curious. Is it possible that connection latency could have resulted in an image that compiled without an avatar?